# Индекс выбранной строки в listView

Tags: c++-cli

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как получить индекс выбранной строки таблицы `listView`?

Comment: какой "фрейворк" используете? чистый winapi, mfc, .net, Qt, wx, Gtk, vcl (c Builder), самопал?

Comment: c++\cli ms visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз это c++/cli, тогда идем в msdn и находим там два свойства - [ListView::SelectedIndices Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp) и  [ListView::SelectedItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx).

Первое возвращает список индексов выделенных элементов, второй - собственно список выделенных элементов. Там же есть примеры на разных .net языках. Для индекса одного элемента я не увидел, но можно всегда его получить через массив.

Comment: спасибо, сделал как в примере на msdn

Answer (score 2):

MFC?

```
CListCtrl* pList= (CListCtrl*) GetDlgItem(IDC_YOURLISTCONTROL);
POSITION pos = pList->GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
if(pos == NULL) {
    // нет выбранных элементов
} else {
    // что-то выбрано
}
```

Чистый WinAPI?

Есть [куча макросов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737(v=vs.85).aspx), чтобы самостоятельно не посылать сообщения.

```
// первый выбранный элемент
int iPos = ListView_GetNextItem(hListView, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);
while(iPos != -1) {
    // что-то выбрано, можно обработать
    // получить следующий  выбранный элемент
    iPos = ListView_GetNextItem(hListView, iPos, LVNI_SELECTED);
}
```

Comment: 0-2 :) мимо